# Element '<t t-if="...">' cannot be located in parent view

Tags: odoo

I am trying to customize a report in Odoo 11. I am modifying an XML file, but I am getting this error:

```
File "/home/omar/odoo/odoo11/odoo/models.py", line 3094, in write
    self._write(old_vals)
File "/home/omar/odoo/odoo11/odoo/models.py", line 3260, in _write
    self._validate_fields(vals)
File "/home/omar/odoo/odoo11/odoo/models.py", line 1041, in _validate_fields
    raise ValidationError("%s\n\n%s" % (_("Error while validating constraint"), tools.ustr(e)))
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Error while validating constraint

Element '<t t-if="caseacocher">' cannot be located in parent view

Error context:
View `report_quotation_inherit_demo`
[view_id: 714, xml_id: moduletest.report_quotation_inherit_demo, model: n/a, parent_id: 637]
None" while parsing None:14, near
<data inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
```

Comment: Could you please share your xml?

Answer (score 0):

Go **Settings**, select **User Interface**, and then **Views**. Enter in search field the following view: *report_saleorder_document*. Is a Qweb Type (report).

So, you are trying to inherit from this view and that `t-if="caseacocher"` can't be located here in parent view (`report_saleorder_document`). **You are missing an xpath.**

Where do you want to locate this in parent view? You will need to open this view and find something else from here that you can use in your module instead of that `t-if`. It must be exist here in parent view!
I suggest you to use xpath to find an expression and then put this condition.

For example, if `div` has a class named `page`, then you could use something like:

```
<xpath expr="//div[@class='page']" position="inside">
    <t t-if="caseacocher">
        <!--etc what ever you want put here-->
    </t> 
</xpath>
```

This is just an example, but you can then use your `t-if` inside the `xpath`.

Good luck.